# PHP header not working (GoDaddy)

Tags: php, session, redirect, authentication

I am trying to make a login page but I can't seem to get the header to show up.

```
session_start();

$_SESSION['prevURL'] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

if(!$_SESSION['set'])
{
header("location: main_login.php");
}
```

Comment: Did you try it without the if statement first? Just to see if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment. You cannot show (print, echo) HTML before the Session_start();

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<?php 

session_start(); 

$_SESSION['prevURL']=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; 
//make this $_SESSION[ 'adminSet'] if it 's an admin-only page

if(!isset($_SESSION['set']))                {                   

    header("location: main_login.php");                 }   
?> 
<head>   
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"> </script>    
    <script src="/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"> </script>    
    <script src="/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"> </script>
```

Should be changed to this:

```
<?php 
session_start(); 

$_SESSION['prevURL']=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; 
//make this $_SESSION['adminSet'] if it 's an admin-only page

if(!isset($_SESSION['set']))                {                   

    header("location: main_login.php");                 }   
?> 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>   
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"> </script>    
    <script src="/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"> </script>    
    <script src="/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"> </script>
```

Comment: This `$_SESSION[ 'prevURL']=$ _SERVER[ 'REQUEST_URI']; ` should be changed to `$_SESSION['prevURL']=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];` especially the space in `$ _SERVER` and `if(!isset($_SESSION['set '])) ` to `if(!isset($_SESSION['set'])) `

Comment: Sidenote: Spaces in variables will cause havoc in code. I fixed them, since you missed a few in your edit, especially when it comes to `'set '` where PHP will look for a session named `set ` with a space at the end. Maybe the OP figured it out, but had it been left like that, a future visitor may not know.

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
if(!$_SESSION['set'])
```

generates a warning if the set is not set. The warning generates output and the header is sent. You cannot set a header once the header is already sent.

The fix will be to use the [isset()](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.isset.php) function:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['set']))
```

Comment: I replaced `if(!$_SESSION['set'])` with `if(!isset($_SESSION['set']))` and it is still not working.

Comment: Is this the only code on your page? do you have any content printed before this code? That inclused white spaces

Comment: This code is only on the current page. I am importing code from main_login.php as you saw above. Here is some of the code: `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <?php
   session_start();

   $_SESSION['prevURL'] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
   
   //make this $_SESSION['adminSet'] if it's an admin-only page
   if(!isset($_SESSION['set']))
    {
     header("location: main_login.php");
    }
  ?>
<head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js">
</script>
   <script src="/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js">
</script>
   <script src="/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js">
</script>`